# jQuery importing jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-app-engine

I have an HTML page with jQuery inside and JavaScript.
I'm importing the libraries I need in the head tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://static.jquery.com/ui/css/demo-docs-theme/ui.theme.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/external/jquery.bgiframe-2.1.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/ui/minified/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;libraries=places" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then I'm importing some html with jQuery inside:

```
$('#cliente').click(function(){$('#container').load('/clienti/cliente');});
```

But the jQuery inside the page loaded is not working. (I'm sure the code is right as is working standing alone).

I need to do something? I have tried to import the libraries in the imported page before the script (out of the head), but not working.
I haven't other ideas!

Comment: you need to also load jQuery inside `/clienti/cliente`, but it doesn't make any sense anyhow, `load` won't eval your js as far as I know :S

Comment: Just as an aside, you should not load JS directly from Google Code source control. This is a significant security/stability concern.

Comment: Loading jQuery from `tags/latest` is a recipe for trouble.
Do the server logs show that the `/clienti/client` call is successful?

Comment: The script is working for sure...

Comment: I have tested many things in the while and I know that the scripts in Jquery imported are working, the only one not working is: <script type="text/javascript">
   function initialize() {
    var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
   }
   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  </script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`.load()` only works for HTML](http://api.jquery.com/load/) the way you're using it. (see the section titled "Script Execution").  It won't evaluate any script inside the HTML you load.  What you want is to load it using a suffix, i.e.

```
$('#cliente').click(function(){$('#container').load('/clienti/cliente.html');});
```

Comment: I'm loading from App Engine, so I have no html file, but I'm generating it each call.

Comment: If you're loading straight scripts, than http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/ may work for you.

Comment: Yes, but I can't I need 15 of reputation

Comment: You're allowed to accept with any amount of reputation, so long as it's on your own question.  (I think you can upvote as well, I'm not sure).  I just +1'd your question, so there's some reputation there!

Comment: Done. Thanks for +1. I'm new on this website.

Answer (score 0):

If your JS and HTML must be in the same file, a better way to do this is this way. I believe it will evaluate JS that way.

```
$('#cliente').click(function(){
    $.get('/clienti/cliente', function(data){
        $('#container').html(data);
    });        
});
```

Alternatively, you can pass both items (the HTML and the JS) back as text

```
$('#cliente').click(function(){
    $.getJSON('/clienti/cliente', function(object){
        $('#container').html(object.html);
        $parseJSON(object.jscript);
    });        
});
```

Otherwise, you will need to use `$.get()` and `$.getJSON()` to fetch the html and js in two shots.